# How to change font-weight in javascript for every onchange

Tags: javascript, html, function, fonts, onchange

I made a variable font, that changes font-weight from 101 to 900 and would like to implement it on a website, where, while the user is typing the font is changing its weight with every letter typed

I kind of have this code right now but it only changes it directly to font weight 900 and does't go slowly about it. I am really new to this so I don't know what else to try  Thanks for any help!!

```
<p id="testarea" contentEditable="true">
Type your text here
</p>


<button type="button" onclick="myFunction2()">uncensour</button>

<script>



document.getElementById("testarea").onchange = function() {myFunction()}
document.getElementById("testarea").addEventListener("input", myFunction)
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("testarea").style.fontWeight = "900";
}
function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("testarea").style.fontWeight = "101";
}

</script>
```

Comment: try `onkeydown` instead of `onchange`. that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this by `onkeypress` event.

```js
document.getElementById("testarea").onkeypress = function () { myFunction() }
document.getElementById("testarea").addEventListener("input", myFunction);
var initWeight = 101;
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("testarea").style.fontWeight = initWeight++;
}
function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("testarea").style.fontWeight = "101";
}
```

```html
<p id="testarea" contentEditable="true">
    Type your text here
</p>


<button type="button" onclick="myFunction2()">uncensour</button>
```

Comment: thank you this is perfekt! I wanted to ask is it possible to make the font weight grow faster? because with the command initweight++ it only grows +1 at a time?

Comment: You're welcome, yes it's increasing by one. If you would like to do so just use `initWeight+=100` before setting it. It will be increased to `100` at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can try incrementing the `font-weight` like this.

```
<p id="testarea" onkeyup="myFunction2()" contentEditable="true">
Type your text here
</p>


<button type="button" onclick="myFunction2()">uncensour</button>

<script>

var bold = 100;

// document.getElementById("testarea").onchange = function() {myFunction()}
// document.getElementById("testarea").addEventListener("input", myFunction)

function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("testarea").style.fontWeight = bold;
  bold+=100;
  console.log(bold);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have imported bootstrap for better effects.

TIP: select a font style which has large number of font-weight to see the effect.

```js
document.getElementById("testarea").onchange = function() {myFunction()}
    document.getElementById("testarea").addEventListener("input", myFunction);

    var isItChanges = true;

    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("testarea").style.fontWeight = "900";

        var fontWeight = 100;

        if(isItChanges){

            isItChanges = false;

            var timer = setInterval(()=>{

            fontWeight = fontWeight + 15 ;

            document.getElementById("testarea").style.fontWeight = fontWeight;

            if(fontWeight > 900){
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
            },1);
        }
    }
    function myFunction2() {
        document.getElementById("testarea").style.fontWeight = "101";
        isItChanges = true;
    }
```

```css
 #testarea{
        font-weight: 100;
    }
```

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <p id="testarea" contentEditable="true">
        Type your text here
    </p>
        
        
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction2()">uncensour</button>
```